# What does "^^" mean in Scala library specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

I came across this line of code today

```
def beCapitalizedAs(capitalized: String) = be_==(capitalized) ^^
    ((_:String).toUpperCase)
```

I don't know what "^^" means. I also googled but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Neither could I.  Cant you just run it and see what it does ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is defined on the specs2 [Matcher trait](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-3.8.5/index.html#org.specs2.matcher.Matcher) and is meant to **adapt one matcher to another**.

This means you can change the actual value before doing the match, i.e. in your example `beCapitalizedAs` will do the comparison on a capitalized String before match.

Also see the specs [Matchers guide](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.8.5/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#derive-matchers) for further information.

Comment: I was going to mention the [scaladoc link](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-3.6.2/index.html#org.specs2.matcher.BeEqualTo).